# Return all wordpress custom posts in specific multidimensional array

Tags: custom-post-types, php, tags

How can I get all custom posts (post_type=family_guy) with their ID and all of their tags in multidimensional array?

Here is exactly how I would like my array to look like:

```
$array = array("1" =>   Array(
                       "Peter1",
                       "Lois1",
                       "Megan1"
                 ),  
      "2" =>   Array(
                       "Peter2",
                       "Lois2",
                       "Megan2"
                 ),
      "3" =>   Array(
                        "Peter3",
                        "Lois3",
                        "Megan3"
                 ),
     "4" =>   Array(
                        "Peter4",
                        "Lois4",
                        "Megan4"
                 )
      );
```

In this array, keys will be custom posts IDs, and values will be all tags of that custom post.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm wondering why you tagged the question with `wordpress.com`, is your blog hosted there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does a query for all posts of type family guy, tosses them into the `$fg_obj` then loops through each post, grabs its tags, and creates a flat array of just the tag name. Then that array gets put into a new array with the post ID. This seems like a strange way of getting this info (because I don't know the final purpose of this array), but it should be the format you've requested.

```
$args = array( 'post_type' => 'family_guy', 'posts_per_page' => -1 ); 
$fg_obj = get_posts($args);
$posts_with_tags = array();
foreach($fg_obj as $fg) {
  $tags = get_the_tags($fg->ID);
  $tag_arr = array();
  foreach($tags as $tag) $tag_arr[] = $tag->name;
  $posts_with_tags[$fg->ID] = $tag_arr;
}
```

Comment: That was what I was looking for, but I shortened the code with wp_get_post_tags function. Thank u for solution.